# what is the best approach to build magento 2 application?

Tags: magento2, application

what is the best approach to building Magento 2 application?
what are the advantages/disadvantages?
what is the language I should use in order to build the application, of course, the application should be compatible with IOS/ANDROID.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best approach to building Magento 2 application?

If you're a developer, you should have the knowledge about M2: https://devdocs.magento.com/. Or you can hire some Magento skilled developers - or Magento companies.

> What is the language I should use in order to build the application

Written by PHP and Javascript.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/architecture/tech-stack.html

> the application should be compatible with IOS/ANDROID

We need to use Magento Apis.

> what are the advantages/disadvantages

From my experience:

1) Advantages: there are a lot of benefits

Both Open source and Enterprise versions:

- You can have an e-commerce site with huge built-in functionalities.
- A lot of extensions (paid and free) which you can choose for your site.
- Amazing community - like this page.
- SEO friendly, Multi website - languages - currencies, etc...

https://medium.com/@magentodesignstudio/top-benefits-of-using-magento-ecommerce-platform-for-your-online-business-a3160f5dfdbe

2) Disadvantages:

- Complexity: Hard to learn at the first time because there are a lot of configs.
- Sometimes, you will be stress with the hardware when working with Magento 2.